# Apache 2.4 + SVN authz authentication with mixed authenticated/anonymous access

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, svn, apache-2.4

I'm using Apache 2.4, and I wish to use it without mod_access_compat.

I'm trying to serve SVN repositories, with access control handled by mod_authz_svn.

I want some repos or locations within repos to have read-only anonymous access. I want other repos or locations to require basic authentication.

Apache 2.4 no longer supports the `Satisfy all` syntax, however, mod_authz_svn seems to expect it. How is this supposed to be configured on Apache 2.4?

Apache config:

```
 <Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /usr/projects/svn
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "SVN repository"
        AuthUserFile /usr/project-config/etc/svn-auth-file
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /usr/project-config/etc/svn-access-control
        Require valid-user
 </Location>
```

svn-access-control:

```
# cat etc/svn-access-control
[/]
antiduh = rw

[openprojects:/]
* = r
antiduh = rw
```

I have 5 repos, openprojects is the only one I want to have anonymous read-only access to. I cannot seem to get this to work. Even the [most recent documentation I could find](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/mod_authz_svn/INSTALL) for mod_authz_svn continues to use `Satisfy all`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `mod_access_compat`?

Comment: I can, I just don't want to. If Apache has changed the auth/access model, I want to find out how to do things in the new model.

Comment: Poking around in mod_authz_svn's source, it's looking like it has a hard dependency on  `ap_satisfies(r) == SATISFY_ANY`. I think that means it isn't supported outside of mod_access_compat, but I'll leave the question up for a while if someone else can think of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poking around in mod_authz_svn's source, it's looking like it has a hard dependency on `ap_satisfies(r) == SATISFY_ANY`. I'm not entirely familiar with the Apache API model, but this would appear to indicate that mod_authz_svn does not currently support Apache 2.4's new authentication model.

Since nobody else has come up with an answer or with contrary evidence, I'm going to mark this as the answer.

To make this work under Apache 2.4, load the `mod_access_compat` module:

```
LoadModule access_compat_module libexec/apache24/mod_access_compat.so
```

And then add the `Satisfy any` clause, just as the documentation currently indicates.

```
 <Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /usr/home/antiduh/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "SVN repository"
    AuthUserFile /usr/home/antiduh/svn/etc/svn-auth-file
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /usr/home/antiduh/svn/etc/svn-access-control
    Satisfy any
    Require valid-user
 </Location>
```

Comment: I do have the same issue which troubles me and my colleagues... Do you have any better solution? At least with LDAP used for authentication of users, your solution does not seem to work properly :(

Comment: This took me two days of tearing my hair while getting cussed out by users. The ````Satisfy any```` is what fixed it. Evidently, Apache got upgraded from 2.2 to 2.4 and things went south from there.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the 2.4 equivalent of `Satisfy All` is to enclose the `Require` directives in a [`<RequireAll>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireall) block.  The equivalent of `Satisfy Any` would be a `<RequireAny>` block.

For more information on the changes and equivalents, [this presentation (PDF)](http://www.rcbowen.com/speaks/apachecon/2013/acin24.pdf) by Rich Bowen might be helpful.

Comment: I had tried that - `<RequireAny>Require valid-user</RequireAny>` is what I tried, which doesn't really make a lot of sense, but its all I can attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a separate `Location` without auth for a subset of the SVN protocol commands, such as :

```
<Location /subversion-open>
  DAV                    svn
  SVNParentPath          /path/to/svn-repos/subversion-open
  SVNListParentPath      Off
  SVNReposName           "SVN repos"
  AuthzSVNAccessFile     /path/to/svn-authz-file

  # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    AuthType               Basic
    AuthBasicProvider      file PAM
    AuthUserFile           /path/to/svn-htpasswd-file
    AuthPAMService         httpd_svn
    AuthName               "Open access SVN repos"

    Require                valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

This lets unauthenticated users read the repos, and authenticated users get access according to the `svn-authz-file` rules.
(In this example we also allow auth via PAM for system users as well as those in the `htpasswd` file)